# set a bit with inline asm without btsl instruction

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I want to set a bit at position p without using btsl instruction with inline asm gcc c code. Using btsl instruction is simple:

```
int n,p;
scanf("%d%d",&n,&p);
asm("btsl %1, %0"
:"=m"(n)
:"Ir"(p)
:"cc");
```

I know for setting bit it can be done:

```
n|=1<<p;
```

Now, I'm doing so with inline asm:

```
  asm("movl %1, %%eax;"
      "movl %2, %%ebx;" 
      "shl $1, %%ebx;"
      "orl %%ebx, %%eax;"
      "movl %%eax, %0;"
      
  :"=b"(n)
  :"a"(n), "b"(p)
  :"cc");
  printf("%d\n",n);
```

It seems to me shl instruction doesn't work. For instance n=20=10100. When I try to set the first bit p=1 the result is 22=10110 instead of 21=10101

Comment: Are you counting bits from 0 or 1? Normally the p'th bit would be set using `x |= 1<<p` where the first bit is at p=0. You say ebx (p) is zero, but it looks like you're setting ebx to p-1. Can you give example inputs for n and p where the code produces the wrong result?

Comment: When I do 20 | 1 the result is 22 instead of 21. However you are right about p-1, p is correct, but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: But 22 is correct, if you do the equivalent of `20 | (1 << 1)`. So, *how does it not work for you?* Please [edit] your question with additional information, this is not a forum.

Comment: Also `shl $1, %%ebx` doesn't do what you think it does. It shifts `ebx` by `1` not  `1` by `ebx`. PS: do not use `mov` in inline asm, use only the appropriate constraint instead. You already specified `b` for `p` as input so the compiler already placed it into `ebx`. So `movl %2, %%ebx` just expands to a pointless `movl %ebx, %ebx`. Same for `n`. You forgot to specify `%eax` as output/clobber too.

Comment: Note that you specify `eax` to be an input register but then proceed to overwrite it.  This is not permitted.

Comment: eax is overwritten in this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C. Euclid's Algorithm, and also movl instruction.

Comment: You can overwrite it if you specify it as output (or a clobber but that's not supported if it's already an input). Your code really should just have `shl` and `or` inside it and use constraints for the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Why did you use a redundant `l` operand-size suffix on every instruction except `shl`?  Anyway, hardly matters, I don't see any point to doing this with inline asm.  Just compile `x|=1<<p;` with older GCC (that misses the BTS peephole optimization or chooses not to use it), and look at the asm output ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)), if you're curious what asm sequence would implement this.

Comment: What's wrong with btsl? If it's broken on your CPU, you should just replace the CPU.

Comment: Don't make your question worse by removing details of actual output from your [mcve].  Instead of downvoting, I rolled back your edit that changed the description to just "[doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Folowing Michael's example, I've done clear and toggle as well as set:

```
unsigned long bitset(unsigned long value, uint8_t shift)
{
    unsigned long tmp;

    asm ("mov $0x1, %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "shl %[shift], %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "or %[tempreg], %[val]"
    : [val]"+r"(value),
      [tempreg]"=&r"(tmp)
    : [shift]"cN"(shift));

    return value;
}


unsigned long bitclear(unsigned long value, uint8_t shift)
{
    unsigned long tmp;

    asm ("mov $0x1, %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "shl %[shift], %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "not %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "and %[tempreg], %[val]\n\t"
    : [val]"+r"(value),
      [tempreg]"=&r"(tmp)
    : [shift]"cN"(shift));

    return value;
}
unsigned long toggle(unsigned long value, uint8_t shift)
{
    unsigned long tmp;

    asm ("mov $0x1, %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "shl %[shift], %[tempreg]\n\t"
         "xor %[tempreg], %[val]"
    : [val]"+r"(value),
      [tempreg]"=&r"(tmp)
    : [shift]"cN"(shift));

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using EBX at all?  That's just pointless.  It's also pointless to start and end with `mov` instructions, just tell the compiler the correct registers where you leave stuff, and ask for it in the right register to start with (i.e. the count in ECX).  Also, this is buggy: you write ECX without declaring a clobber on it.  (Downvoted for that bug; inline asm is hard enough to get right without dangerous examples of using it wrong.  I'd be happy to remove it if you reduce this to just the 3 instructions "necessary", or grudgingly if you just make it safe but still inefficient garbage.)

Comment: If you are really intent on using those 3 instruction (a mov/shl/or) then you can do it this way : https://godbolt.org/z/MvKnsa

Comment: bitclear still only needs 3 instructions; you can rotate `0xFFFFFFFE` to put the zero where you want it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, Could you just write this example? I've never seen such as method to clear.